# Feature not supported: endSessions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

Error: The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "code": 303, "errmsg": "Feature not supported: endSessions", "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1687796034, "i": 1}}}
I am not using session for DocumentDB on on server restart it shows this error

my connection String
"mongodb://"+  + ":" + +"/?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false"

I am Using spring Template

I know that documentDB doesn't support endsession do I need to explicitly turn it off using any config?

I tried changing this upgrading my java client but that did not help